# How do you add some steps to a capistrano task?

Tags: capistrano

I'd like to stop some processes before running the deploy:migrate task.  I know that I can redefine the deploy:migrate task by copying the existing code and adding the stop/start steps at the beginning and end of the task.

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid copying the code from the default deploy:migrate task in my version of the task.  Is there a way to refer to the existing deploy:migrate task when defining a new task of the same name?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Rather than redefining `deploy:migrate`, you should define a before or after hook for it. First, create a new task that does the stuff you need to do:

```
task :custom_name do
  # whatever you need to do
end
```

And then set this new task to be run before or after the `deploy:migrate` task by doing one of the following:

```
before "deploy:migrate", :custom_name
after "deploy:migrate", :custom_name
```

Answer (score 0):

For my requirements, I override the existing task in deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do
  # to Override deploy:migrate task
  task :precompile, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "your modified commands"
  end
  # to override deploy:assets:precompile task
  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      run "your modified commands"
    end
  end
end
```